# Android - Accessing views in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer activity where i am attaching different fragments

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, rp_fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, sensors_fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, stats_fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

I'm trying to modify the text property of a textview contained within a fragment but i keep getting a null pointer exception on the view (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.teicrete.alucard.sempi.sensors_fragment.ctv_tvst(int)' on a null object reference).

Mainactivity:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, new rp_fragment());
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, new sensors_fragment());
            ft.commit();
            gentempdata();
            sensors_fragment sf = (sensors_fragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_sensors);
           sf.ctv_tvst(1);
```

Fragment:

```
    public class sensors_fragment extends Fragment {
            // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
            // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
            private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
            private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

            TextView ctv_tv;
            TextView otv_tv;
            View view;
    ...

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sensors, container, false);
            TextView ctv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv);
            TextView otv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.otv_tv);
            //ctv_tv.setText("Test");   Only this works
            return view;
        }    
...

        public void ctv_tvst(int mtext) {
            ctv_tv.setText(mtext);
        }
```

I've looked at similar posts here but i was not able to resolve my issue. The only place where i am able to modify the textview is within the onCreateView of the fragment (see code above). If i try to do it from the mainactivity or anywhere else i get the null pointer error.

Any insights?

Edit: Please see my response in android_griezmann's post.
For now, i am doing everything that i need to do, inside the fragment classes themselves and then i load them. I would still like to figure out why i can't access its methods or views externally.

Answer (score 1):

Change those lines from onCreateView:

```
 TextView ctv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv);
 TextView otv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.otv_tv);
```

To:

```
 ctv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv);
 otv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.otv_tv);
```

Currently you are assigning reference to new object by `TextView ctv_tv` but actually you want this reference to be assigned to class field so you don't have to add `TextView`.

Comment: I made this change and i'm still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `Fragment` itself not the `TextView`. You are getting fragment object as null not the textview.

So try to find the fragment like the below.

```
if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, new sensors_fragment(),"YOUR_TAG_NAME");
        ft.commit();
        gentempdata();
        sensors_fragment sf = (sensors_fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TAG_NAME");
        sf.ctv_tvst(1);
    }
```

Also change this method too!

```
public void ctv_tvst(int mtext) {
    ctv_tv.setText("" + mtext);
}
```

Comment: I believe that you might be correct that the fragment is null. I also tried for example sf.getView() instead of my custom method and i got the same error. However, assigning a tag just like you pointed out, did not fix the problem. I've also assigned an ID to its layout file but this also doesn't work.

Comment: @PanagiotisMoraitis are you getting the same error after finding a fragment through `TAG`?

Comment: Yes indeed. Gettting the same error with TAG as well. As i said i think you are correct about the fragment being null. Cant figure out why though!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sensors,container, false);
     TextView ctv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv);
     TextView otv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.otv_tv);
     //ctv_tv.setText("Test");   Only this works
     return view;
}
```

with

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sensors,container, false);
         ctv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv);
         otv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.otv_tv);
         //ctv_tv.setText("Test");   Only this works
         return view;
    }
```

Create a variable `String ctv_tv_string` and assign the value in `ctv_tvst()` method do not assign to the `TextView`. it would not throw an error as you are not referring any ui element after this in `oncreateview` `ctv_tv.setText(ctv_tv_string)`

Comment: here is the reason to your problem! you getting this error because you are ctv_tvst method because even fragment onCreateView() is called!

Comment: Create a String variable ctv_tv_string and assign the value in ctv_tvst() method do not assign to the TextView. it would not throw an error as you are not referring any ui element after this in oncreateview  ctv_tv.setText(ctv_tv_string)

Comment: @Tulsi In your answer u r saying the user is un nessarily creating two new objects.. can u explain where he is doing it ??

Comment: this line TextView ctv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv);

Comment: i don't see any object creation there.. Objects in java are created using new keyword.. Object obj = new Object(); in the above code  TextView ctv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv); he is just referring the view by declaring ctv_tv as TextView.. and declaration will not result in object creation

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

TextView ctv_tv = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv);
TextView otv_tv = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.otv_tv);

        }
```

override onactivity created, and then refer your views.. Infact it is the best place to get reference to your views withot getting NullPointer Exception

Comment: There is no onActivityCreated method on my Fragment class.

Comment: @PanagiotisMoraitis how is tat possible??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data while replacing or adding then pass the data in your fragment constructor like below

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, new sensors_fragment("your data"));
        ft.commit();
```

Then in your fragmet change the textview value based on the constructor's data

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem. Just remove the ***TextView***

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sensors, container, false);
        **TextView** ctv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ctv_tv);
        **TextView** otv_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.otv_tv);
        //ctv_tv.setText("Test");   Only this works
        return view;
    }
```